# Do beta hydroxy aldehydes respond to Fehling's test?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Do beta hydroxy aldehydes respond to Fehling's test?

I was told that it readily loses a molecule of water forming alpha beta unsaturated compound. But it still has an alpha hydrogen and I presume that it meets all requirements for a compound to respond to Fehling's test.

Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: If it's an aromatic aldehyde, Fehling's test anyways not gonna work. But if it's an aldehyde not having a bulky side group, I think it should respond. It is not so spontaneous for any $\beta$-hydroxy aldehyde to lose a water molecule to form the unsaturated aldehyde.